# difference between rows within groups pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Dataframe:

```
col1   col2
a       50
b       40
a       40
a       30
b       20
a       20
b       30
b       50
```

I need to group them based on col1 and sort them highest to lowest based on col2 for each group
and find difference between consecutive row in the group.
dateframe:

```
col1  col_entity col2   diff   
a        a1       50     10     
b        a2       40     10     
a        a3       30     10    
a        a4       20     nan    
b        b1       40     10     
a        b4       50     10     
b        b3       30     10     
b        b2       20     nan
```

Please help me on this
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please don't change your question after answers are posted to your original question. If you want a different question answered you can do this in another post.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I apologise for the same I am new to posting questions here will follow this from the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
#replaces any value that contains a string value, with a 0
df['col2'] = pd.to_numeric(df.col2, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
#sorts the column in ascending first and calculates the difference 
df['diff']=df.sort_values(['col1','col2'],ascending=[1,1]).groupby('col1').diff()
#display the dataframe after sorting col1 in asc and col2 in desc
df.sort_values(['col1','col2'],ascending=[1,0])
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: thank you sir your answer is great but
I have changed edited the question

Comment: I am getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign and groupby col1 then use diff to compute the difference.

```
(
    df
    .assign(diff = lambda x: x.groupby('col1').diff())
    .sort_values(['col1','col2'],ascending=False)
)
```